# CSS trick to add margin on Carto's embedded iframe (for mobile)

Tags: carto

I am using carto on [my website](http://www.city-safe.com/) through embedded iframes, and I have an issue on mobile : the map takes the full width of the screen, making it hard to scroll to the bottom of the page, as can be seen on the pic.

Could anyone give me a CSS workaround to give all the iframes a left and right margin? Given that I cannot add the margin to the containers directly.

[image]

```
<iframe width="100%" height="520" frameborder="0"    src="https://topraf.cartodb.com/viz/5c19c6fe-34bc-11e6-a91c-0e31c9be1b51/embed_map" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

In [this webpage](http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/a/iframes-and-css.htm) is explained how to give CSS styles to your iframe.It might be useful for your use case. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CSS, I will recommend disabling the `Scroll wheel zoom` option. This will allow users to scroll down the whole mobile page but the map.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but it's already disabled! I also tried to disable the Zoom Controls but it doesnt work either

Comment: I have reported the issue to the CARTO's Product team [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/9585).